# How to check at runtime if an imageview came from a local or remote resource?

Tags: android, imageview, android-image, image-loading, bitmapdrawable

If I'm running as a third party library within an android application, and I want to check whether the imageviews on screen were loaded from locally bundled resources or were loaded from a remote uri - is there a way of doing this at runtime? Is there perhaps some clue in the view tree that would help me group the imageviews into these two broad categories? I see that the uri field itself isn't providing anything useful by reflection. I can ask developers to tag the imageviews but that creates a substantial overhead for them that I prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

No.  ImageViews hold Drawables.  The view has no idea where that drawable came from.  It doesn't even know what type of Drawable it is.

Also, using setImageUri to show a remote image is generally a code smell-  that causes it to request and decode on the UI thread, which can be a cause of performance issues.  You should never be doing that, and use an external image cache to download images and properly thread things.  There's a few large image libraries out there that do it for you (Glide and Picasso being the big two)